# Webpack: how can I keep the output not flatten?

Tags: javascript, gulp, webpack

How can I keep the output not flatten?

```
"entry": {
    "head": path.join("js/user/resume.js"),
    "login": path.join("js/login/login.js"),
}
```

expected output structure:
`dist/js/user/resume.js`,
`dist/js/login/login.js`

Is there a config options like Gulp's `base`?

Answer (score 0):

```
entry:{
    'user/resume': path.join('js/user/resume.js'),
    'login/login': path.join('js/login/login.js')
}
```